Elementary matrix trace example for calculating Lefschetz number?
For $f : X \rightarrow X$, The Lefschetz number is given by nLab as $$ \Lambda_f  = \sum_{i\ge0}(-1)^k \text{tr}\, (H^i(X, \mathbb Q) \xrightarrow{f_{i}^*} H^i(X, \mathbb Q) )$$
I wanted an explicit computation of what the trace could be. I want to make sure that I understand what the matrix trace is in this situation (mentioned by wikipedia). I dug around on nLab for a few hours, but I wasn't able to personally find anything that dealt with the computation directly and wasn't Categorical abstract nonsense. I want to set up some matrices in a very elementary way, and make sure I understand the computation.
Let the cohomology group for some $H^i$ be, say $\mathbb Q \oplus \mathbb Q \oplus \mathbb Q$. Since this is a graded module, can I give it a column vector representation $$ \left(\begin{array} a a \\ b \\ c\end{array} \right)$$
Now, have the overall map be an identity map. Then would the induced map on the homology groups be given as $$\left(\begin{array} 1 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{array} \right)  \left(\begin{array} a a \\ b \\ c\end{array} \right) $$
where the the trace of $f^*_i$ is the trace of the identity matrix, which is three? In a more general sense, would I treat my cohomology groups as being column vector representations of the graded algebra, and my linear transformation $f^*_i$ as being a matrix of a similar form? Then have a more general linear map for some $k$-dimensional graded module as
$$\left(\begin{array} A A_{11}  & \cdots &  A_{1k} \\ \vdots  & \cdots &  \vdots\\ A_{k1}  & \cdots &  A_{kk}\end{array} \right)  \left(\begin{array} a 
m_1 \\ \vdots \\ m_k \end{array} \right) $$
from which I would take the trace of the matrix?

I know this sounds elementary, but I couldn't find it anywhere online, and I haven't constructed linear transformations back out of graded algebras before. Thanks in advance.

I give two examples here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249439/computing-lefschetz-number/1250326#1250326

In your example, yes, $f$ acts as the identity matrix, but its Lefschetz trace depends on the degrees in which those three copies of $\mathbb{Q}$ live, which you haven't specified.

@QiaochuYuan using voigt notation as I am, would degree manifest itself as a scalar multiplication of the identity?
